# Merging geopandas dataframe and converting to json throws "Maximum recursion level reached" error

Tags: pandas, geopandas

Dataframe df has following columns:

```
['country_code', 'confirmed_cases', 'count_date']
```

gdf (geopandas dataframe) has following columns:

```
['country_code', 'geometry']
```

All of the following work:

```
df.to_json()
gdf.to_json()
gdf.geometry.to_json()
```

But when I merge both I cant convert to json.

```
merged_df = df.merge(gdf, how='left')

merged_df.country_code.to_json() #works
merged_df.count_date.to_json() #works
merged_df.confirmed_cases.to_json() #works

merged_df.to_json() #THROWS MAX RECURSION ERROR
merged_df.geometry.to_json() #THROWS MAX RECURSION ERROR
merged_df.iloc[:1].to_json() #THROWS MAX RECURSION ERROR
```

Why is the same 'geometry' column behaving differently in two dataframes?

Answer (score 2):

Merge the files in the other way. Since `gdf` is GeoDataFrame, `to_json` has to deal with geometry column. Pandas can't to that by itself. If you merge `gdf` to `df` as you did, your result is pandas.DataFrame. If you merge the other way, your result will be geopandas.GeoDataFrame which can handle exporting geometries to json.

```
merged_df = gdf.merge(df, how='right')
```

Comment: Thanks you. Its working for 10K rows but when I try for full dataset (~43K rows) operation gets killed. Any way to solve this? I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: Is it possible that you run out of memory? 43K is not so huge though.

Comment: My machine has 4GB RAM. May be higher RAM will solve it?

Comment: Yes, 4GB RAM could be the culprit, especially if parts of it are used by the system and other apps.